# How do you check if a file description is empty or not in Expressionengine 2?

Tags: expressionengine

I am using Expressionengine 2. I would like to check to see if the file description is not empty so that if there is any content it will be used instead of the entry title in the alt tag.

Currently I have the code below which brings in the entry title but I can't work out how I get the logic in place to check the existence of descriptive text for the file (image):

```
<img class="aClass" src="{work_detail_extra_image_01}" 
alt="
    {if work_detail_extra_image_01:description != ""}
        {work_detail_extra_image_01}{description}{/work_detail_extra_image_01}
    {if:else}
        {title}
    {/if}
" 
border="0" />
```

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `!= ""` so that line becomes:

```
   {if work_detail_extra_image_01:description}.
```

It'll see if it exists or not.

I'd try to display the description there first without conditionals to make sure they aren't your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. Unfortunately this didn't work. What I was trying to do was get to the description in the same way as you can is you have done any image manipulation but that doesn't seem to work and looking about I can't find anything relating to trying to take this approach which usually leads me to believe that there is a better way to do it. I am going to change my approach and post back my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img class="aClass" src="{work_detail_extra_image_01}" 
alt="{work_detail_extra_image_01}
    {if work_detail_extra_image_01:description != ""}
        {work_detail_extra_image_01:description}
    {if:else}
        {title}
    {/if}
{/work_detail_extra_image_01}
" 
border="0" />
```